# Set attachment category from file name on upload

Tags: uploads, taxonomy, attachments

I use Media Library Assistant plugin and I extensively take advantage of its taxonomy, in particular the possibility of creating categories that can be assigned to images (categories that you define are actually the terms of a custom taxonomy category defined by MLA plugin and named "attachment_category").

MLA plugin already allows to manually set categories on bulk uploads of attachments, but I'd like to push further this feature adding a functionality that automatically sets categories on attachments upload by retrieving them from the name of the uploaded files, provided that the file name contains such information in a format that could simply be a list of comma separated values inside square brackets, like the one used by [some file tagging software](https://docs.tagspaces.org/tagging#file-tagging-based-on-filename).

Thanks in advance for any clue on how to achieve such powerful functionality, which would allow a seamless integration between offline and uploaded attachments, and a very powerful management of image galleries especially if in conjunction [with this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/282270/113609).

Comment: Is there any code or pseudocode of what you have tried to do?

Comment: @CelsoBessa Actually no, I'm too weak on Wordpress to think of some code from stratch. If someone helps with some draft code I could work on it though.